# Is there a way to implement a pie look instead via Material Spinner component or some other component usable by Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to change the look of a project to have its progress of a data piece using a more pie chart look instead of the thin line used with Materials Spinner. I know you can change the diameter and stroke width of it but when I change it does not look clean. In order to smooth it back out to a circle shape the component ends up taking up more space then I would like.

Any suggestions of how to alter it or other components to use via angular UI would be appreciated.